# Where is this file located on device?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm using the react-native-camera module in order to record video. After it records it gives me the uri of the location of the .mp4 video as:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.cassette_code/cache/Camera/a608b09c-e572-4056-9927-c0e8988cd254.mp4
```

I don't know where this is located. I recorded this on an android phone. Could someone tell me where I can access it, or if I can specify the location where the video should be stored in my project directory? I looked through the phone's storage, but I don't see com.cassette_code. I'm running it through my phone using USB debugging, so that might be why. But where would it be?

Comment: The path you wrote down is the exact location of your file. And you can access it there. And it is already in your project directory. And ES FileExplorer or other file managers will not show it.

Answer (score 0):

open your file manager in your android phone then select internal storage then android file  then data file and finally select your app file

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install something like ES File Explorer, then find the file using that app. Most built in file browsers can't see the application files